# Can't add items to my ListView in fragment [Android]

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am a novice android developer.
I am building an app which accepts data from a JSONArray accessed via an API, and puts the contents of the JSONArray into a ListView.
The code for adding the items to list is given below.

```
public void AddToList(JSONArray array)
    {

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
        {

            try
            {
                JSONObject state= array.getJSONObject(i);

                String item1=state.getString("item1"), item2=state.getString("item2");

                list.add("Item1: "+item1+"\n"+"Item2: "+item2);

            }

            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The items are being added to the list because the same code worked with the listView not being inside a fragment. However, now it shows just a blank page.

The layout code is given below:

```
<!-- state_frag.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code for switching between tabs is also given here, just in case.

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener listener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            fragment = null;
            switch (menuItem.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                {
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.nav_states:
                {
                    fragment = new StatesFragment();
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.nav_about:
                {
                    fragment = new AboutFragment();
                    break;
                }
            }

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_container, fragment).commit();

            CallToAPI call=new CallToAPI();
            call.execute("API URL");

            return true;
        }
    };
```

Edit: Fragment code is given below:

```
// StatesFragment.java

public class StatesFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.states_frag, container, false);
    }
}
```

What is the issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Show your fragment code.

Comment: @dominicoder the question has been updated!

Comment: That can't be the extent of your fragment. You have no other logic other than `onCreateView`??